# Reading a text file in iOS using std C++

Tags: c++, ios, std

After reading a lot of related SO questions, I am still wondering:

Is it possible to read a (text) file in iOS using only `std C++` in a cpp file on iOS?

Comment: Hugh?? What's actually hindering you, clarify please! I don't understand the upvote for that poor question either (someone driving sock puppets or what?).

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ What's "hindering me" is the fact that I want to use C++ not objective c.

Comment: Your question seems doomed, unless you show an attempt and explain, where it actually fails.  As is, it looks like some _"Gimme teh codez plz and a cheeseburger on top"_ question. Refine please to improve!

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ This question asks about feasibility, not about specific code

Comment: Just use any of the standard C library IO functions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible.

Your source file should be a `.mm` file and to get the path of the file you should use Objective-C classes. The path will likely be an `NSString` which is convertable to an `std::string`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was hoping to find a way of achieving file access in a uniform way on both android and iOS...